# ArcGIS-R bridge on a Linux server?

Tags: arcmap, r, linux

After reading a bit about the ArcGIS-R bridge (https://r-arcgis.github.io/) it seems like the bridge is only designed for Windows, but that seems a bit odd, I think. Is there a possibility to install an ArcGIS-R bridge on a Linux server between R 3.4.4 and ArcMap 10.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArcGIS-R bridge is not a client-server system, its core is code that reads ArcGIS objects. That code is linked to ArcGIS code.

Since you can't run ArcGIS on Linux or Mac (without Windows OS emulation) there's no way this can be installed on those platforms.